# Автоматическое экспортирование HTML классов в SCSS

Tags: html, css, phpstorm, scss

Доброго времени суток.

Имею следующий  код:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent__elem">Бэм элемент блока parent</div>
</div>
```

В IDE Visual studio Code есть замечательный плагин, который по выбранному фрагменту HTML документа экспортирует в буффер обмена все классы учитываю БЭМ как в примере ниже. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kvxymatt.class-extractor
Этот функционал очень упрощяет верстку, подскажите, есть ли похожий метод по быстрому эскопртированию html классов внутрь scss с поддержкой бэма? (как в примере - чтобы был символ амперсанда).

```css
.parenent {
  &__elem{}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, такой функциональности в PhpStorm нет; проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за [WEB-19236](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19236), чтобы получать уведомления об обновлении статуса этого запроса